# Configuring Apache virtual hosts

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I've my AWS EC2 hostname, `ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`, and its public IP, `55.XX.XX.XX`.

Apache vhost config path: `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

I'd like to create virtual hosts like below

```
dev.ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (or dev.55.XX.XX.XX.com)  - /var/www/html/dev
uat.ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (or uat.55.XX.XX.XX.com )  - /var/www/html/uat
```

I tried creating dev.conf in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` but it did not work for me.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com.com
    ServerName  dev.ec2.XX.XX.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/dev"
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Could some one please explain me how to create vhosts like above?

Comment: Do you have a directory by name "dev.ec2.XX.XX.com"

Comment: You'll also have to enable the VHost: `sudo a2ensite dev.conf` and restart the server.

Comment: error2007s and hjpotter92 - Yes, I have directory `dev.ec2-xx-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com`  and I did `sudo a2ensite dev.conf` and  restated the the server. Please suggest

Comment: What happens when you access `dev.ec2....` address?

Comment: I see "Server not found error " message , here is the screenshot for the same [link]https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Vt30oJm1sHNnU5aWgyZDctMjg

Comment: could some one please help me on this...it is kind of road blocker for me